# ip-телефония на Gstremer

Tags: python, rtp

Здравствуйте. Стоит задача реализовать ip-телефонию в рамках одного роутера между устройствами (телефон/ноут/ПК с микроконтроллером по Wi-Fi) по протоколу RTP. Вопрос, стоит ли использовать фремворк Gstremer? 
Так же буду благодарен за готовые решения на python))

Answer (score 0):

Конечно стоит! Для быстрой разработки и такой же быстрой работы это идеальный вариант.

Вам необходимо только обменяться между клиентами адресами и портами. Внутри локальной сети это удобно подписавшись на мультикаст, как сделанно в [Pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#PulseAudio_.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B7_.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.8C) и у Эплов.

Начни с [документации](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp.html) . Многое можно реализовать не написав ни строчки кода, а только зарустить [пайп](https://habrahabr.ru/post/178813/) через gst-launch и уже услышать звук на другой стороне.

Это очень удобно в случае контроллеров. Ведь не надо тащить целый питон на маленькую железку.

Приложения на Python пишутся довольно легко. Просто повторяешь пайп уже в коде. Только нужно привыкнуть к стилю glib, когда понадобится более глубокая настройка.

Очень много [ссылок](https://habrahabr.ru/post/179167/) выдает поиск. Приводить их все нет смысла - лучше начни писать код и задай вопрос когда что-то не выйдет.